# Force same type on function parameter and nested object property

Tags: typescript

I have a function with the following signature, which is a helper function that will append a value to a list property on an

```
export function append<
    T extends Entity, 
    S extends Collection<T>
>(state: S, entityId: number, path: string | string[], value): S {}
```

It is based on the following two simple interfaces

```
export type EntityId = number;

/**
 * Interface for entities
 */
export interface Entity extends Object {
    readonly id: EntityId;
}

/**
 * Interface for collection-based state
 */
export interface Collection<T extends Entity> extends Object {
    readonly entities: { [key: string]: T };
    readonly ids: EntityId[];
}
```

Example usage would look like

```
interface Comment extends Entity {
    text: string
    likedByIds: number[]
}

interface CommentState extends Collection<Comment> {}

const comment: Comment = { id: 1, text: 'hello', likedByIds: [] }
const commentState: CommentState = {
    entities: {
    1: { id: 1, text: 'hello', likedByIds: [] }
    },
    ids: [1]
}
const commentWithLike = append(commentState, 1, 'likedByIds', 555)
commentWithLike // { id: 1, text: 'hello', likedByIds: [555] }
```

The goal is for the above, to enforce that the type of the likedById passed in conforms to the interface, ie. only allow numbers and fail if I for example tried to pass in the ID as a string `"555"`

Is this possible? Much appreciated

Comment: Your code does not compile, you define `export type EntityId = string;` but you use `number` as ids

Comment: Sorry, fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't type a whole path (`path: string | string[]`) but you can ensure that `path` is a property of `T` and `value` is of the same type as the `path` property:

```
export function append<
    T extends Entity,
    TKey extends keyof T,
    >(state: Collection<T>, entityId: EntityId, path: TKey, value: T[TKey]): Collection<T> {
    return state;
}
const commentWithLike = append(commentState, 1, 'likedByIds', [555]) // OK
const commentWithLike2 = append(commentState, 1, 'likedByIds', '555') // error
const commentWithLike3 = append(commentState, 1, 'likedByIds', 555) // error
```

Notice that I did not use `S extends Collection<T>`. This is because there are limitations in the way typescript infers generic parameters, so using `S` as you did in the function signature, would have cause `T` to always be inferred as `Entity` not `Comment`.

While this may be good enough for some use cases if you want to have a specific type for the collection you can do one of two things:

In typescript 2.8 (unreleased at the time of writing, scheduled for March 2018, but you can get it using `npm install -g typescript@next`) you can conditional types to extract the entity type:

```
export function append<
    S extends Collection<any>,
    T = S extends Collection<infer U> ? U : never,
    TKey extends keyof T = keyof T,
    >(state: S, entityId: EntityId, path: TKey, value: T[TKey]): S {
    return state;
}
```

Or before ts 2.8, you could declare the `append` method on the `Collection` removing the need to infer `S`

```
export interface Collection<T extends Entity> extends Object {
    readonly entities: { [key: string]: T };
    readonly ids: EntityId[];
    append<TKey extends keyof T>(entityId: EntityId, path: TKey, value: T[TKey]): this
}
const commentWithLike = commentState.append(1, 'likedByIds', [555])
```

**Edit - Support for paths**

Took some time to get it to work properly but here is a workable solution:

```
type PathHelper<T> = { <TKey extends keyof T>(path: TKey): PathHelper<T[TKey]>; Value?: T; };
type Path<TSource, TResult> = { (source: TSource): TResult, fullPath: string[] };
function path<TSource, TResult>(v: (p: PathHelper<TSource>) => PathHelper<TResult>): Path<TSource, TResult> {
    let result: string[] = [];
    function helper(path: string) {
        result.push(path);
        return  helper;
    }
    v(helper);
    return Object.assign(function (s: TSource) { throw new Error("Do not call directly, use path property") }, {
        fullPath: result
    });
}

type CollectionType<S> = S extends Collection<infer U> ? U : never;
export function append<S extends Collection<any>,
    TValue>(state: S, 
            entityId: EntityId, 
            path: Path<CollectionType<S>, TValue>,
            value: TValue): S {
    console.log(path.fullPath);
    return state;
}

//Usage:
interface Comment extends Entity {
    text: string;
    comment?: Comment; // added for nested object example
    likedByIds: number[]
}
interface CommentState extends Collection<Comment> { }

const comment: Comment = { id: 1, text: 'hello', likedByIds: [] }
const commentState: CommentState = {
    entities: {
        1: { id: 1, text: 'hello', likedByIds: [] }
    },
    ids: [1]
}
const commentWithLike2 = append(commentState, 1, path(v => v("comment")("likedByIds")("length")), 5)
```

**Notes**
The `path` function takes a function in from which you will have to return the path by calling the parameter which is a function returning a function. Each time you call it you navigate into the object.

The `path` function returns a `Path` object, which has a call signature, and a `fullPath` property. The `fullPath` property should be used, the function signature should be ignored. Typescript does an interesting form of back inference when a function returns a function, and this function signature that `Path` has, saves us from having to specify a type parameter to `path`, and allows the compiler to infer the starting type for `path` based on the parameters to `append`

You could keep a simple signature to append that takes a `string` for simple paths.

Comment: Is there any solution (hack or not) to how we can have type-safe paths?

Otherwise, this is perfect as I'm already using 2.8, thanks!

Comment: @Tarlen I created a solution for type safe paths, hope it helps and is not too esoteric to actually use, let me know what you think about it :)

Comment: @Tarlen I saw you added a new similar question for paths :) this was a bit to weird ?

Comment: Yes, I realised that I can can just hardcode the level of nesting and use the other approach for the path as I think it will lead to a cleaner API